# Spring Boot REST API will not start when importing a dependency from a different application module

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, dependencies

I am building a REST API with Spring Boot as our other API uses Drop-wizard and does not use Spring. I need to use some code, specifically JMS code to send messages to various different parts of an application, hence the build of a new API so we can import dependencies from different modules. I have the API working perfectly, until I import a dependency which I need to access the already written JMS code.

I have been through various different sources to try and find if there are any mismatched versions between my spring boot dependencies and the spring dependencies that the other module uses.

I have consulted my colleagues (who have 30 years experience between them) and are unable to come up with an answer.

I have tried using different versions of spring-boot to see if this fixes the problem.

I am using the following parent version of Spring-Boot

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
```

And then using the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I can send various different GET & POST requests to the different endpoints and everything is working fine, until I place this dependency into my pom.xml (Which is from another module of a production system):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.kinesisfleet.messaging</groupId>
    <artifactId>kinesis-messaging</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The pom for this particular module of the system uses spring using the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The versions of Spring we use are the following:

````
```Spring Version - 4.2.0.RELEASE
Spring Data Version - 1.8.2.RELEASE
Spring Integration Version - 4.1.6.RELEASE```
````

Once the dependency is added, I cannot start the app and get the following error:

```
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:201) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:92) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:673) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at com.kinesis.spring.api.KinesisCoreSpringApi.main(KinesisCoreSpringApi.java:21) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.core.BridgeMethodResolver.findBridgedMethod(BridgeMethodResolver.java:60) ~[spring-core-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.<init>(GenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor.java:70) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.buildGenericTypeAwarePropertyDescriptor(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:348) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:175) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:212) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:63) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHandler(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:725) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.isWritableProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:557) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE



    It looks to be some sort of version mismatch, between the imported 
    dependency and the spring boot parent version.

    I am finding this very frustrating ad have spent nearly two days 
    trying to figure this out. Although im a junior dev, i've fixed 
    these sorts of issues lots of times, but this one if proving 
    difficult.

    If anyone has any ideas or pointers It would be appreciated

   Thanks
```

Comment: try to upgrade your module to use spring 5. the same version that your spring boot version uses.

Comment: I dont think that will be possible. Ive been told I need to make it work with the current spring versions :/

Comment: then you should not use spring boot then, because it requires the version of spring that you are not prepared to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by adding the spring dependencies required for the dependency that was causing the issue! Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 0):

You can try printing the dependency tree in maven using this command 
`mvn dependency:tree`
to see which version is causing the issue when adding the dependency